# action on cotangent bundle is symplectic

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Edit: I think my original formula for the induced action had some mistakes, which I believe I've corrected.

If a Lie group $G$ acts on a manifold $X$, there is an induced action on $T^*X$ by pulling back. Explicitly, if $\alpha=(p,\alpha_p) \in T^*X$, we can define a new one-form $g\cdot \alpha \in T^* X$ above $g \cdot p$: for any $v=(g\cdot p,v_{g\cdot p}) \in TX$
$$
(g\cdot\alpha)(v):= \alpha_p\big((\rho_{g^{-1}})_*(v_{g\cdot p})\big) = \alpha_p\big((\rho_g^{-1})_*(v_{g\cdot p})\big)\equiv \big((\rho_g^{-1})^*\alpha_p\big)(v_{g\cdot p})
$$
where $\rho_g: X \to X$ is the diffeomorphism of $g$ acting on $X$. $T^*X$ is canonically an exact symplectic manifold with primitive one-form given by, for $v = (p,v_p) \in T(T^*M)$ with $p \in T^*M$ and $v_p \in T_p(T^*M)$,
$$
\lambda(p,v_p) := p \cdot \pi_*(v_p)
$$
and symplectic form given by $\omega = d\lambda$. In coordinates, $T^*X$ has the form $(q_1,\dots,q_n,p_1,\dots,p_n)$ where $q_i$ are coordinates on the base space and $p_i$ are the fiber coordinates. We have
$$
\lambda = \sum_i p_i dq_i
$$
We must be careful with notation here since we are dealing with an induced action by pullbacks. If $\rho_g: X \to X$ is the diffeomorphism associated to the action of $g$ on $X$, then $(\rho_g^{-1})^*: T^*X \to T^*X$ is the induced diffeomorphism on cotangent bundle. Denote this by $\Phi_g$. Then we must show that
$$
\big((\rho_g^{-1})^*\big)^*\omega \equiv(\Phi_g)^*\omega = \omega
$$
Note that $\Phi_g^*$ preserves $\omega$ if it preserves $\lambda$, by naturality of pullbacks wrt differentials. So it suffices to compute
$$
\Phi_g^*(\lambda) = \Phi_g^*\left(\sum_i p_idq_i\right)
$$
$$
= \sum_i \Phi_g^*p_i \wedge d\left(\Phi_g^*q_i\right)
$$
$p_i$ and $q_i$ are functions on the manifold $T^*U$, so pullback acts by precomposition:
$$
=\sum_i (p_i \circ \Phi_g)d\left(q_i \circ \Phi_g\right)
$$

But I do not know how to proceed from here. I have encountered some coordinate free calculations online but right now I'm interested computing the pullback in coordinates directly.

Comment: Notice that the group action is irrelevant here. If you see that a diffeomorphism of M induces a symplectic diffeo of the cotangent bundle what you want follows at once. You can this remove remove all references to groups and actions here.

Comment: So suppose you have a diffeo f from M to M. Pick a point p, a chart phi defined on an open set containing f(p), notice that phi\circ f is a chart defined on an open set containing p. Now use those charts to construct charts of the cotangent bundle, and see what is the pullback of the symplectic form the explicitly.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think I understand. In that case, isn't what I have completely correct? Like my last line is exactly the definition of the tautological one-form in the 'domain' coordinates.

Comment: Actually, even with this new viewpoint I think my calculation is still off by a factor of $d$. If I take coordinates $(q_i,p_i)$ around $f(p)$, shouldn't the coordinates around $p$ in $T^*U$ be given by $(q_i\circ f, d(q_i \circ f)) =(q_i\circ f, p_i\circ df)$, since for cotangent bundle, the fiber coordinates are just exterior derivative of the manifold coordinates? In that case, my final answer says $p_i \circ \Phi_g$ where it should say $p_i \circ d\Phi_g$?